# node.js aws sns difference between console test and npm run publish'ed message

Tags: node.js, amazon-sns

I publish a message to Amazon SNS to be read by a lambda function.

In my testing I am using 2 methods to invoke the lambda function;

1. AWS console Lambda > Functions > 22-generic-subscription
2. using AWS CLI `$> npm run invoke-test-sns`

where package.json contains

```
  "scripts":
  {"invoke-test-sns": "aws sns publish --message file://message.txt --subject TestMsg --topic-arn ${npm_package_SNS_srcARN}"
  }
```

message.txt;

```
{
  "test": "cli",
  "length": "20",
  "width": "6"
}
```

Obviously the code doesn't change , but the results from the two invocations are unexpected, I have reduced the code to highlight the differences;

Code ;

```
/*
**    22-generic-subscription
*/
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

console.log('Loading function');

// START
let area;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
try {

var jMsg = event.Records[0].Sns.Message

console.log('messageConsole: 1-');
var messageConsole = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jMsg));
console.log('messageConsole: ', messageConsole);
console.log('messageConsole: ', messageConsole.test);

console.log('messageCLI: 1-');
var messageCLI = JSON.parse(jMsg);
console.log('messageCLI: ', messageCLI);
console.log('messageCLI: ', messageCLI.test);

console.log('messageCLI.stringify: 2-');
var messageCLI2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jMsg));
console.log('messageCLI2: ', messageCLI2);
console.log('messageCLI2: ', messageCLI2.test);
}
catch (err) {
console.log(err);
return err;
}
return area;
};
```

To setup the test from the console -
select **AWS Console > Configure Test Event > Amazon SNS Test Notification** and change the Message element as follows by copying and editing the contents of message.txt;

```
    "Message": {
      "test": "console",
      "length": "10",
      "width": "5"
    }
```

I changed the test value to indicate how the test was invoked i.e. console or cli.

Here are the results;

**Console Test 1**

> START RequestId: 2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0 Version: $LATEST
> 2021-01-02T23:12:03.891Z    undefined   INFO    Loading function
> 2021-01-02T23:12:03.896Z    2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0    INFO    messageConsole: 1-
> 2021-01-02T23:12:03.898Z    2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0    INFO    messageConsole:  { test: 'console', length: '10', width: '5' }
> 2021-01-02T23:12:03.898Z    2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0    INFO    messageConsole:  console
> 2021-01-02T23:12:03.898Z    2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0    INFO    messageCLI: 1-
> 2021-01-02T23:12:03.898Z    2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0    INFO
> **SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**
> END RequestId: 2b671ef5-06f1-45f2-9501-e797997eb2c0

**CLI Test 2**

> START RequestId: c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d Version: $LATEST  
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageConsole: 1-  
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageConsole:    
> {  
>     "test": "cli",  
>     "length": "20",  
>     "width": "6"  
> }
>
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageConsole:  **undefined**
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageCLI: 1-
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageCLI:  { test: 'cli', length: '20', width: '6' }
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageCLI:  cli
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageCLI.stringify: 2-
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageCLI2:
> {
> "test": "cli",
> "length": "20",
> "width": "6"
> }
> 2021-01-02T23:14:24.944Z    c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d    INFO    messageCLI2:  **undefined**
> END RequestId: c5e4a0f3-50ac-4031-af0e-4dfb581ccb4d

Apologies as it may not be clear that in Console test 1 - the CLI code fails and in CLI test 2 - the console code fails.
Can someone explain why the results are different and how I can write my code to act the same way no matter how the test is called ?

Answer (score 0):

- Lambda is called for one or more SNS messages in single call, so, you will get an array of message, never a single json. format of the message is [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html)
- Actual message sometimes is zipped and base64 encoded depending upon the how message is written to SNS. For example Cloudwatch subscription filter to SNS.

So, we always need to loop through Records and process each message not just the first record event.Records[0]..

Input passed from AWS console should also be exact same format as what we get from SNS.
From CLI
aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:my-test-topic --message '{"test":"cli","length":"20","width":"6"}'

From Console: message should be in Sns.Message within Records array.

```
{"Records":[{"Sns":{"Message":"{\"test\":\"cli\",\"length\":\"20\",\"width\":\"6\"}"}}]}
```

and to print the incoming messages in node

```
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    const snsMessage = JSON.parse(record.Sns.Message);
    console.log("Sns Message", snsMessage);
  });
```

Comment: I tried passing `'{"test":"cli","length":"20","width":"6"}'` via CLI, within message.txt and I got the same results, with and without the quote character. Separately from within AWS console, I also tried formatting the message with backslashes '\' to escape the double quotes and got the same errors, so my understanding is still incomplete, please could you review?

Comment: you can pass `'{"test":"cli","length":"20","width":"6"}' `directly to  with --message like my example OR you can keep the json directly in message.txt and pass file://message.txt , like you did. Both should work fine. Important thing is what format you are passing from Lambda console

Comment: sorry, just to re-cap; as per the original post everything is / has been working for both the CLI and the console, but strangely with different code!? Do I need to change my code or is there some peculiarity with my message formatting?

Comment: @chris-j in my example, I am passing a string from the cli and from the console. I edited answer to add a little loop to print them. Overall in your question, the input you are passing from Lambda console seems incorrect format.